# Postgres - how to bulk insert table with foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am looking to do a bulk insert into my postgreSQL database.

- database is not yet live
- postgreSQL 13

I have a temporary staging table which I bulk inserted data

```
TABLE public.temp_inverter_location
(
    id integer ,
    inverter_num_in_sld integer,
    lift_requirements character varying,
    geo_location_id integer NOT NULL (foreign key references geo_location.id),
    location_name character varying,
    project_info_id integer NOT NULL (foreign key references project_info.id)
 )
```

I am trying to populate the two foreign key columns `temp_inverter_location.geo_location_id` and `temp_inverter_location.project_info_id`.

The two referenced tables are referenced by their id columns:

geo_location

```
CREATE TABLE public.geo_location

    (
        id integer,
        country character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        region character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        city character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
        location_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",

    )
```

and

project_info

```
CREATE TABLE public.project_info
(
    id integer 
    operation_name character varying,
    project_num character varying(10),
    grafana_site_num character varying(10)
)
```

I want to populate the correct foreign keys into the columns `temp_inverter_location.geo_location_id` and `temp_inverter_location.project_info_id`.

I am trying to use [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) to populate `temp_inverter_location.geo_location_id` with a `JOIN` that matches `geo_location.location_name` and `temp_inverter_location.name`.

I have tried this query however `inverter_location.geo_location_id` remains blank:

```
INSERT INTO temp_inverter_location(geo_location_id) SELECT geo_location.id FROM geo_location INNER JOIN temp_inverter_location ON geo_location.location_name=temp_inverter_location.location_name;
```

Please let me know if more info is needed, thanks!

Comment: try the select statement till you get all data with joins and what you need and then use the code to replace the select that you have so far, but as nobody knows the layout and the result you want, nobody can help you .see [mre]

Comment: Hard to say without the schema definitions for the tables involved. Does `temp_inverter_location` not already have the values for the FK fields? The issue I coudl see is that the tables `geo_location` and `project_info` did not exist when you did the INSERT or they exist but the parent value of the FK relationship was not in them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - so I'll provide snapshots

Comment: So does `temp_inverter_location` have values for the `geo_location_id` and `project_info_id`? If not then you can't do what you want as you are working from the wrong end of the relationship. What does `SELECT geo_location.id FROM geo_location INNER JOIN temp_inverter_location ON geo_location.location_name=temp_inverter_location.location_name;` by itself yield?

Comment: Hi Adrian, yes, the common information they share is in `temp_inverter_location.location_name`, `geo_location_id.location_name` and `project_info.operation_name`.

I actually resolved the challenge by using update between two tables with the connecting item being `location_name`/`operation_name` as show in https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/

Can I ask what approach you would take?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - just realized my last question may sound snarky - it's not, it's genuine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using [update](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/) referencing another table.

Basically, I updated the geo_location_id column using

```
 UPDATE temp_inverter_location SET geo_location_id = geo_location.id FROM geo_location WHERE geo_location.location_name = temp_inverter_location.location_name;
```

and updated the project_info_id using

```
UPDATE load_table SET project_info_id = project_info.id FROM project_info WHERE project_info.operation_name = load_table.location_name;
```

It seems to have worked.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that helps with `project_info_id`?

Comment: Sorry, the answer was incomplete.  Here is the `project_info_id` included.